# How to convert web site language into user selected language - React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, frontend, language-translation

I have developed a site with **React js** in English language but I want to have the feature of changing site language to user preferred language. How can I achieve this?.

Comment: Take a look https://react.i18next.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some good packages for achieving this, you can try out [i18n-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-react) or [react-i18next](https://react.i18next.com/) both packages offer a good way of adding internationalization to your site. I like the later and according to their documentation achieving this would be like this.

`<div>Just simple content</div>`

to

`<div>{t('simpleContent')}</div>`

Where `simpleContent` is the defined key in the i18n file which has different translations, so you can give the user the option to choose a language, which would change the component's language based on the selected language, to achieve this you need a more concrete setup, check the documentations on the above links.

Answer (score 0):

a better library I'll suggest will be the i18next. it's quite straight forward and easy to implemente:

brief explanation here: https://dev.to/ksushiva/how-to-translate-your-react-js-app-with-i18next-12mn

official doc: https://www.i18next.com/overview/comparison-to-others